# XPages form won't save field values if save button is within a xe:dialog

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I have a Xpage with two custom controls containing editable fields tied to the single data source on the Xpage.    On the Xpage I use a xe:dialog that contains a button to save the data source document1 (using SSJS).  No validation is occurring yet. I use a xe:dialogButtonBar to call the xe:dialog (using CSJS) which opens fine and then click the OK button containing Action Save Document data source.

diablogButtonBar onClick call to open dialog.

```
XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialogSaveAsDraft}");
```

With this configuration the document is saved but the editable fields are not created nor data saved. The Xpage has the following two properties set, computeWithForm: onsave, action:editDocument but have tried createDocument too.

Here is the twist: If I take the button in the xe:dialog and place it outside the xe:dialog, the button works and the Xpage and all editable fields save properly.

What am I missing? I have done almost exactly the same thing before but instead of using the xe:dialogButtonBar I used a string of buttons.  I wanted to use the xe:dialogButton Bar to organize the UI.

Can some one explain why that would occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about the form submission. When you launch the dialog, editable fields on the other parts of the page are not submitted (dialog is launched upon partial refresh). Therefore the back-end component tree is not aware of the field updates of the client-side.

You can either open the dialog from the SSJS (so it submits the page) or create a "noupdate" submission with `onComplete` script to launch the dialog.

```xml
<xp:link
    escape="true"
    text="Open Dialog with SSJS"
    id="link1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh"
        action="#{javascript:getComponent('dialogSaveAsDraft').show()}">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
<xp:link
    escape="true"
    text="Open Dialog with onComplete"
    id="link2">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="norefresh"
        onComplete="XSP.openDialog('#{id:dialogSaveAsDraft}');">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was afraid of.  It looks like I can not use the method you suggested with the xe:dropDownButton though. It doesn't like the onComplete property and looks to be pure CSJS.  I will need to find a different method or just use a string of Buttons/links at the top of the form.

Comment: You can use it. Instead of CSJS, use submit value and onItemClick event. You might use SSJS to launch any dialog depending on the submit value. (you can use `context.getSubmittedValue()`)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ComputeWithForm then you have to have a DisplayErrors control. That is where validation error messages will appear. Do you have that? If not you could be getting a validation error from the formulas on the form and they have no place to display the error messages. By the way, using ComputeWithForm is not really a good thing to do. You should repeat your validation logic directly on the XPage. Otherwise, you got too many things going on, the validation/translation that happens at the XPage level and again at the form level.

Comment: I am not doing any validation yet. I wanted to get the basic functionality working before I convert the Notes logic to SSJS or CSJS.  I was just saving what ever values are entered.  I do have a Messages control but it isn't showing up since there are no errors.  The document is saved with the two fields containing hard-coded values but any editable fields are not even part of the document.